# Create heatmap from dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, data-science

How can I make a heatmap for `Year`, `State` and color by `Engine`?

```
Year    Make    Engine  State          Tally
2012    Acura   2.4     Rhode Island    1
2013    Acura   3.5     Rhode Island    1
2012    Acura   1.8     Rhode Island    1
2013    Acura   2.4     Rhode Island    1
2015    Acura   2.4     Rhode Island    1
2016    Acura   2.4     Rhode Island    1
2015    Acura   3       Rhode Island    1
2017    Acura   1.8     Rhode Island    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sns   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

heatmapdata = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Engine', index=['State'], columns='Year')
sns.heatmap(heatmapdata, cmap="YlOrRd")
```

df is the name of your dataframe.